# Get IPAddress of a podman container

Tags: ubuntu, wsl-2, pgadmin-4, podman

I'm trying to connect connect my postgre DB (in a container) using pgadmin (in a different container).

I tried using the inspect command but the IPAddress is just an empty string:

```bash
$ podman inspect serene_lovelace | grep -i ipaddress
```

returns

```bash
            "IPAddress": "",
```

Edit:

Turns out the IP I needed is just the WSL2 intance's IP, here's how I obtain it:

```bash
ip addr | grep 172
```

returns

```bash
    inet 172.26.240.194/20 brd 172.26.255.255 scope global eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the ip address, use inspect -f to extract it

```
podman container inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' serene_lovelace
```

Comment: Tried that and still empty string

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the `podman inspect` general output for a container.
The exact answer may depend :

1. It can be :

```
    podman container inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' <your_container>
```

2. Or if you have specific named  in NetworkSettings, you will access to it using :

```
    podman container inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.<MyNetwork>.IPAddress}}' <your_container>
```

where:

- <your_container> the container whose IP we are looking for
- <MyNetwork> the name of your custum podman network

Regards,

PS: I do not have permission to comment (for answering
*Topaz Rindu Nabiyallah*) so I added my answer normally (but point 2) may solved the 'empty string' bad result.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dynamic script to have an overview about IP-s of running containers, jq must be installed. Some of us might have dynamically changing networks under different users when running podman in rootless mode.

```
#!/bin/bash    
for container_id in $(podman ps -q); do
            json=$(podman inspect  $container_id)
            container_ip=$(echo "$json" | jq -r '.[].NetworkSettings.Networks | to_entries[] | .value.IPAddress')
            container_name=$(echo "$json" | jq -r '.[].Name')
            echo "Container Name: $container_name, Container ID: $container_id, IP Address: $container_ip"
    done
```